# Ruby Class from .rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I like to read ruby files from the filesystem and get the actual ruby class

```
Dir["app/controllers/admin/*.rb"].select{ |f|
    require File.expand_path(f)
    #how to turn 'f' into an actual class
}
```

The problem I have is that both Kernel.load or require just respond with a boolean. Is there a way to get the actual class. I know that I can use the file path to determine the name, but I like not to deal with namespaces. How can I do that?

Comment: There is exactly zero correspondence between files and classes in Ruby. A single class may be defined in multiple files, and a single file may define multiple classes or even no classes at all. And what should your proposed method return for a file that contains e.g. something like this: `if rand < 0.5 then class A; end else class B; end end`?

Comment: I had a similar problem once. My solution was to require the files to be a specific format, and to load them with `instance_eval` instead of `require`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag yes yes, I know. I am dealing with files where there is only one class in the file. And yes there is no relation between file name and class name. I like to get the one and only class from the file and determine if its based on a certain BaseClass. For all files in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm going to tell you up front that this is probably a bad idea. Files in Ruby have no relationship to classes whatsoever. A file can define one class, no classes, or many classes, and it can even define classes dynamically based on arbitrary conditions. Additionally, class definitions might be spread across multiple files, and classes can be altered dynamically at runtime. For this reason, determining reliably whether a class is defined in a file is a difficult task, to say the least.

That said, here's one way you might approach the problem. Note that this solution is very hacky, won't work in all cases, and it *can* load the same file more than once if you're not careful:

```
module ClassLoader
  def self.load_classes(file)
    context = Module.new
    context.class_eval(File.read(file), file)
    context.constants.map{|constant| [constant, context.const_get(constant)]}.to_h
  end
end
```

Usage:

`./test_file.rb`:

```
if rand < 0.5
  class A
  end
else
  class B
  end
end

class C
end
```

Your code:

```
ClassLoader.load_classes('./test_file.rb') #=> {:A=>#<Module:0x9a3c128>::A, :C=>#<Module:0x9a3c128>::C}
```

Alternately, if you're using Rails class names can often be inferred from the file name. This is somewhat more dependable, since it relies on the same conventions that Rails does for autoloading constants:

```
Dir["app/controllers/admin/*.rb"].select{ |f|
    File.basename(f).camelize.constantize
}
```

Comment: Its not working for me. i have rails controllers here: /app/controller/admin/, when i read them with 'load_classes' I get {} or 'NameError: wrong constant name #<Module:xxxx>'. Any idea why this isn't working with RailsControllers?

Comment: You have basically re-implemented the behavior of `Kernel#load`, which already takes an optional boolean argument telling it whether to evaluate the contents of the file within a module. And you have the exact same problem `Kernel#load` has: I can just simply use absolute constant references in the file instead of relative references, i.e. just use `class ::Foo; end` instead of `class Foo; end` to "break out" of the module.

Comment: @JörgWMittag `Kernel#load` won't let you access the module that it's wrapping the file with. My implementation needs to be able to do that in order to call `constants` on that Module. And yes, there are a number of problems with this implementation, which is why I stated up front that it is "hacky" and "won't work in all cases". I'll update my answer to make it even more clear that this is a bad idea.

Comment: @StanWiechers No idea why it's not working in your case. It's hard to tell without more information. Check the line the error is occuring on, I don't think an error message like that could occur inside the code I gave you. (My guess is you're mistakenly using `const_get` on the values in the hash returned by `load_classes`. Though again, I can't be sure since I can't see your code.)

Comment: @Ajedi32 @ JörgWMittag I can reproduce this error 'NameError: wrong constant name #<Module:0x...>'  with this class basic class https://gist.github.com/whoisstan/5f77f6c7aa021de27600. I am running Ruby 2.1.2 on OS X. Does the above gist work for you?